# Google apps script - Comparing initial values of a range after edit

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm pretty new to Google Apps Script/Javascript, so this could be a really simple answer. I'm trying to send several emails when certain cell values are changed in a spreadsheet. Below is my working code. I have this set up to run onEdit. However, it sends an update any time a cell on the sheet is modified where I just want one email sent when the certain cells (Balances) are modified.

```
function sendUpdate() {
var recipients=["User1@gmail.com","User2@email.com"];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get the range of cells that store balances
  var sslink = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl()
  var Balances = sheet.getRange("A28:C31").getValues();
  var User1Balance = Balances[2][2];
  var User2Balance = Balances[3][2]
  var User3Balance = Balances[0][2]
  var User4Balance = Balances[1][2]
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

   GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients[i],
                     'Utilities Spreadsheet updated',
                      "This is an automated email generated from the utilities spreadsheet being updated. " +
                      "Current balances are: " +
                      "\n\n User1: " + User1Balance + "\n User2: " + User2Balance + "\n User3: " + User3Balance + "\n User4: " + User4Balance +
                      "\n\n Access the spreadsheet at: " + sslink);


  }
};
```

I tried using the onOpen function to read in the initial values and then compare these values each time it the sheet was edited. However, I was having some problems passing the initial data into the my main function above. Any advice on how to go about this would be great. I thought it would be easy using a global variable, but not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you suggest is a bit complex, why not simply check if the edited cell is included in your balance range ?

You can get the rowIndex and columnIndex using `getRow()` and `getColumn()` and simply check these value to see if the active cell (the one being modified) is in this range.

something like that maybe ?

```
function sendUpdate() {
var recipients=["User1@gmail.com","User2@email.com"];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get the range of cells that store balances
  var sslink = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl()
  var Balances = sheet.getRange("A28:C31").getValues();
  var User1Balance = Balances[2][2];
  var User2Balance = Balances[3][2]
  var User3Balance = Balances[0][2]
  var User4Balance = Balances[1][2]
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
   var col = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
    if(row>=28 && row<=31 && col<=3){

     GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients[i],
                     'Utilities Spreadsheet updated',
                      "This is an automated email generated from the utilities spreadsheet being updated. " +
                      "Current balances are: " +
                      "\n\n User1: " + User1Balance + "\n User2: " + User2Balance + "\n User3: " + User3Balance + "\n User4: " + User4Balance +
                      "\n\n Access the spreadsheet at: " + sslink);

    }
  }
};
```

note :  I didn't test but the idea seems to be valid...

As for the other approach, there is no direct way to use global variables (defined outside of all functions) to be updated during script execution by a function. They will keep the value they have when the function is executed. However, you could achieve the same behavior using a 'permanent storage'  to store the values, for example using scriptProperties.
Since your balance range is not too big this could be quite easy to implement... but still far more complex then the first solution I suggested. If you want to go this way, feel free to ask for help if you need to.

Comment: I figured I would end up having to take a different approach. That worked, thanks for the idea!

Comment: glad it helped. If ever you have *some free time* you can give a try to the scriptproperties, it's opening a whole lot of possibilities too ;-)